# Adding sublists to their own list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, beautifulsoup, sublist

I am trying to create a program that takes nba team data from various websites and compiles stats in the form of a list to each team.

I.E: Atlanta = ['107.5','105.6','.516','.543']

With the numbers meaning points per game, opponents points per game, RPI, and rebound percentage.

I'm running into an error right now just trying to figure out how to take a user input, finding the list of that team in a list of lists, and extracting a certain index from that list.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.espn.com/nba/stats/rpi"), "lxml")
data = [[x.text for x in row.find_all("td")] for row in soup.select("table tr")]
tables = []
team_s = []
for row in data:
   tables.append(row)
team_s = [item[0] for item in tables]
team_s = [el.replace('\xa0',' ') for el in team_s]   
print (team_s[2])

print ("-" * 80)
print ("Welcome to the NBA betting helper. \nTo start, enter the city of the home team for team 1. Then enter the city of the away team for team 2.")
print ("-" * 80)
home = input("Enter the city of team 1 (Home Team):")
away = input("Enter the city of team 2 (Away Team):")

Atlanta = []
Boston = []


try:
   print (team_s.index("Detroit"))
except ValueError:
   print ("word1 not in list.")

def hometeam():
    print ("ex")        

def awayteam():
    print ("ex")     

#Main

hometeam()
awayteam()
```

Comment: I can't see rebound percentage column in the table. What do you mean by that?

Comment: `"I'm running into an error right now"`, and that error is...?

Comment: Sorry, I am also using this link:http://www.espn.com/nba/statistics/team/_/stat/team-comparison-per-game

But the error was that when I went to index the sublist I was getting that it was out of range. I am all set now though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list that contains a dictionary for each team with the key as the team name and value as a list of stats (RPI, PF, PA).

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.espn.com/nba/stats/rpi"), "lxml")
>>> data = [[x.text for x in row.find_all("td")] for row in soup.select("table tr")[2:]]
>>> stats = {team[1]: [team[2], team[8], team[9]] for team in data}
>>> print(stats)
```

Partial Output:

```
{'Golden State': ['.571', '6853', '6376'], 'Houston': ['.562', '6504', '6007'], 'Toronto': ['.553', '6376', '5892'], 'Boston': ['.543', '6085', '5878'], ...}
```

Note that I've sliced the `soup.select(...)` list with `[2:]` since the first 2 lists don't contain stats of teams.

Where, the format of dictionary is `{'team_name': [RPI, PF, PA]}`. I've not added rebound percentage since I can't find it in the table. But I'm sure you can add that looking at the above code.

Now, you can take input from user and print the corresponding stats like this:

```
>>> home = input("Enter the city of team 1 (Home Team): ")
Enter the city of team 1 (Home Team): Boston
>>> print(stats[home])
['.543', '6085', '5878']
```

Comment: @JackHudgins, please note the change in the `data = ...` line, I've changed it from a list to a dictionary.